# Printing specific characters from a char Array

Tags: c++, c-strings

Im working on this program where a user will enter a "S" or "Sell, and the program looks for those cstring values in the char array and If found will return the menu option starting from the first '\n' and the last '\n'. So entering 'S' or 'Se' will return '2. Sell'. This is where I'm stuck on.

UPDATED! Now just trying to see if I can pull in that '#. ' when a solution is selected? (if possible)

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


void promptForInput(char list[]) {
char *strPtr = nullptr;
const int ANSW = 10;
char line[ANSW];
int num = 0;

cout << "Enter an option: ";
cin.getline(line, ANSW);

strPtr = strstr(list, line);
while (strPtr[num] != '\n' && strPtr[num] != '\0')
{
    cout << strPtr[num];
    num++;
}


}

int main()
{
int count = 0;

char menu[] = "1. Buy\n2. Sell\n3. Convert\nX. Exit\n";

while (menu[count]){
    cout << menu[count];
    count++;
}

promptForInput(menu);
```

}

Comment: Do you have to return only those options which start with `Se`? Also, If multiple options are these with `Se`, What are we supposed to do?

Comment: As you've likely noticed, entering 'S' or 'Sel' return "Sell
3. Convert
X. Exit". This is because you haven't thought about an appropriate data structure to streamline the process. If you decide to keep the C-style strings then you also need to parse out the selections that is picked. to find a proper start position and also its end, i.e., '\n'.

Comment: Since this is C++ you should be using `std::string` whenever possible and avoid using C-style raw character buffers.

Comment: The line `list[index];` doesn't do anything. You fetch a value and discard it. It's also far from clear why you're displaying your menu text one character at a time when `cout << "1. ...\n";` would do the job.

Comment: [Your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would like to discuss the `while (list[index] != '\0')` loop with you.

Comment: My plan of action is to use a loop to count the char starting at the 1st '\n' on the left and right of that specific char, or chars select. Would a while loop to retrieve the char value until it hits the '\n' work ? Also, is my plan of finding that first '\n' on the left as the starting point for the while loop a good idea?